# Disable Date-picker when other input field has value

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two input fields one of them is a date-picker

I want to allow filling one only

I succeed in locking the other one when the date picker is filled
but I couldn't do the opposite

**How to do so ?**

```
<label>Event Date (English)</label>
<input type="text" name="edateen" id="datepicker" class="edateen">
<br><br>
<label>Event Date (Arabic)</label>
<input type="text" name="edatear" id="edatear" placeholder="1438-04-18">
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});

$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#datepicker").keypress(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

  $('input.edateen').on("change", function(){
          if($.trim($(".edateen").val())){
            $('#edatear').attr("disabled", "disabled");
          }else{
     $('#edatear').removeAttr('disabled'); 
    }  

  });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Somayah/f3w0vhtg/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems, in the line:

```
('#edatear').on("change", function () {
```

you should add the `$` symbol:

```
$('#edatear').on("change", function () {
```

So, to disable the datepicker, you should replace:

```
 $('#datepicker').attr('readonly',false).datepicker();
```

to:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```

To get properly disabled.

To enable just change the `true` to `false` like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker( "option", "disabled", false );
```

There is the example working: https://jsfiddle.net/f3w0vhtg/10/

Answer (score 0):

I see there is an issue with your selectors. Try this code instead.

```
$("#edatear").on("keypress keyup",function(){
  if ($("#edatear").val() !== '')
        $("#datepicker").attr("disabled","disabled");
  else
    $("#datepicker").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```